# how to have make a web service for android applications

Tags: android

I want to make a web service for android application and only accepts every request that come from my application not other applications like jquery in web and other android applications
anyone can help?

Comment: You have to make webservice with some web based technologies such as ASP.NET or PHP. Host it on a server and code your android application webservice calling

Comment: please clarify: you don't know how to make a web service in general, or don't know how to make your service accept requests only from your app?

Comment: @Vlad Matvienko
I want to accept requests only from my app

Comment: then use some header or parameter that will identify your app. Like is there is an `apiKey=thisisreallymyapp` parameter in each request, then it is your app.

Comment: @Vlad Matvienko
This way you say has a bug and if someone know the app request can send request to server from every where that possible

Comment: It is not a bug, and there is no other way unfortunately. You have to make it the way that nobody can know that.

Answer (score 1):

Build a Simple REST API for Mobile Applications using PHP or .Net.. PHP such Laravel already have API configuration and REST APi Authenticate in it can be simply setup..

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer but I want to accept requests only come from my app